# How Do I Populate a ComboBox With an Existing Array

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

When I try to edit details of an existing item, my code fails to fill in the corresponding information for the last two items in the list. There is a combobox for selecting the item to edit, then a textbox for the item ID, as well as a textbox for the dates the item was ordered and when it was shipped, then two more comboboxes for selecting the shipping status and the online store it was purchased through. These fields are all auto-filled with the corresponding information for the item that is selected. The details corresponding to the selected item can be edited with the exception of the item name itself and the item ID. It works for every item EXCEPT the last 2 items and I have no idea why. Here is the code for editing an existing item:

```
Option Explicit


Private Sub cboOrderedFrom2_Change()

    cboOrderedFrom2.BackColor = vbWhite
    lblOrderedFrom2.ForeColor = vbBlack

End Sub

Private Sub cboOrderStatus2_Change()

    cboOrderedFrom2.BackColor = vbWhite
    lblOrderStatus2.ForeColor = vbBlack

End Sub

Private Sub cboRemoveOrEditItemDetails_Change()

    cboRemoveOrEditItemDetails.BackColor = vbWhite
    lblItemDescription2.ForeColor = vbBlack

    Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Integer, wsLR As Variant

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    wsLR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Rows

    For i = 3 To wsLR

        If ws.Cells(i, 2) = Me.cboRemoveOrEditItemDetails Then
            Me.txtItemID.Value = ws.Cells(i, "A")
            Me.txtPiecesIncluded2.Value = ws.Cells(i, "C")
            Me.txtOrderDate2.Value = ws.Cells(i, "E")
            Me.cboOrderStatus2.Value = ws.Cells(i, "G")
            Me.txtQuantityOrdered2.Value = ws.Cells(i, "D")
            Me.txtDateShipped2.Value = ws.Cells(i, "F")
            Me.cboOrderedFrom2.Value = ws.Cells(i, "H")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i

End Sub

Private Sub cmdAddStore_Click()

    frmAddStore.Show

End Sub

Private Sub cmdCancelEditOrRemoveItemDetails_Click()

    Unload Me

End Sub

'Private Sub cmdRemoveItemDetails_Click()

    'Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Integer, wsLR As Variant

    'Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    'wsLR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Rows

    'For i = 3 To wsLR

        'If ws.Cells(i, 2) = Me.cboRemoveOrEditItemDetails Then
            'Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
            'Sheet1.Activate
            'Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
            'ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value + 1
            'Unload Me
        'End If

    'Next i

'End Sub

Private Sub cmdSubmitEditItemDetails_Click()

    If txtPiecesIncluded2.BackColor = vbRed Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If txtQuantityOrdered2.BackColor = vbRed Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If cboOrderStatus2.BackColor = vbRed Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If cboOrderedFrom2.BackColor = vbRed Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If cboRemoveOrEditItemDetails.Value = "" Then
        cboRemoveOrEditItemDetails.BackColor = vbRed
        lblItemDescription2.ForeColor = vbRed
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If cboRemoveOrEditItemDetails.BackColor = vbRed Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Integer, wsLR As Variant

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    wsLR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Rows

    For i = 3 To wsLR

        If ws.Cells(i, "B") = Me.cboRemoveOrEditItemDetails Then
            ws.Cells(i, "A") = Me.txtItemID.Value
            ws.Cells(i, "C") = Me.txtPiecesIncluded2.Value
            ws.Cells(i, "E") = Me.txtOrderDate2.Value
            ws.Cells(i, "G") = Me.cboOrderStatus2.Value
            ws.Cells(i, "D") = Me.txtQuantityOrdered2.Value
            ws.Cells(i, "F") = Me.txtDateShipped2.Value
            ws.Cells(i, "H") = Me.cboOrderedFrom2.Value
            Unload Me
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i

End Sub

Private Sub spnPiecesIncluded2_Change()

    txtPiecesIncluded2.Value = spnPiecesIncluded2.Value

End Sub

Private Sub spnQuantityOrdered2_Change()

    txtQuantityOrdered2.Value = spnQuantityOrdered2.Value

End Sub



Private Sub txtPiecesIncluded2_Change()

    If IsNumeric(txtPiecesIncluded2.Value) And txtPiecesIncluded2.Value >= spnPiecesIncluded2.Min And _
    txtPiecesIncluded2.Value <= spnPiecesIncluded2.Max Then
        spnPiecesIncluded2.Value = txtPiecesIncluded2.Value
        txtPiecesIncluded2.BackColor = vbWhite
        lblPiecesIncluded2.ForeColor = vbBlack
    Else
        txtPiecesIncluded2.BackColor = vbRed
        lblPiecesIncluded2.ForeColor = vbRed
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub txtQuantityOrdered2_Change()

    If IsNumeric(txtQuantityOrdered2.Value) And txtQuantityOrdered2.Value >= spnQuantityOrdered2.Min And _
    txtQuantityOrdered2.Value <= spnQuantityOrdered2.Max Then
        spnQuantityOrdered2.Value = txtQuantityOrdered2.Value
        txtQuantityOrdered2.BackColor = vbWhite
        lblQuantityOrdered2.ForeColor = vbBlack
    Else
        txtQuantityOrdered2.BackColor = vbRed
        lblQuantityOrdered2.ForeColor = vbRed
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub
```

Comment: Will you edit your post to include the code for the module where you create the array as well. Someone may want to see it to see how you form your array.

Answer (score 2):

Populating a `ComboxBox` is pretty straight forward. The `.List` property can accept an array, or you can add items individually with the `.AddItem` method.

I notice from your code that you are reading each cell at a time in to your array. Are you aware that you can do it all in one go? Let's say your code to define the desired range looks something like this:

```
Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long
Dim readRange As Range

'Define the range to be read
With Sheet1
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set readRange = .Range(.Cells(3, "A"), .Cells(lastRow, lastCol))
End With
```

Then the code to populate your array, could simply be one line:

```
Dim data As Variant

'Read range to array
data = readRange.Value2
```

The same applies to writing your array to a `Worksheet`:

```
Dim writeRange As Range

'Write the data
Set writeRange = Sheet2.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(data, 1), UBound(data, 2))
writeRange.Value = data
```

Below are three examples of populating your `ComboBox` with all or part of the array:

```
'Populate the combobox
UserForm1.ComboBox1.List = data

'Or, if you want more than one column in combobox
With UserForm1.ComboBox2
    .ColumnCount = UBound(data, 2)
    .List = data
End With


'Or, if you want a specific index (not the first) from your array
Dim r As Long, index As Long
index = 2
For r = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
    UserForm1.ComboBox3.AddItem data(r, index)
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and your advice! I ended up completely rebuilding the project in a new workbook last night. I found a solution to the combo box population problem, but now I have a new problem: When editing an existing item, I can select an item in the combo box and it auto-fills the corresponding details from the table into the necessary fields, all except the last two entries which will not fill in the corresponding information. I will post all the code I have written for all to see and maybe tell me where I have made a mistake! Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. I'd recommend you ask that as a new question.